# top output, relationship between virt and mem% for a process

Tags: bash

my computer has ubuntu 14 installed. There are a total of 40 CPUs, and 260G memory.

I use top command line to check the status of the processes. I was expecting that for each individual process, the virt value should be approximately equal to 260 * mem%. However, it is not.

Could you anyone help me to figure out why?

Thanks for any input:))

Answer (score 1):

The `MEM%` column shows the amount of *physical* memory that is being used by a process. This amount is called the "Resident Set Size" (RSS) and is given in the `RES` column. The amount of virtual memory on a system is effectively unlimited due to the fact that each process has their own [LDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Descriptor_Table) (on x86; other architectures' MMUs have their own equivalents).